# Object with url as data source renders with broken styling only in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-object

I have an object element (not my choice, just helping a friend fix his stuff) that gets data via a hyperlink so it looks like

`<object name="testObject" width="100%" scrolling="no" data="https:// <long url here>" style="height:600px" type="text/html"></object>`

In Chrome, FF, etc. it looks fine but in IE 11 it DOES render but it is like the Bootstrap and jQuery used to style the content is broken: media queries are not taking effect so it always has "mobile" classes attached, certain elements are pushed around, there is a y-scroll bar even though the object specifically has scrolling="no", etc. I can even copy and paste the url of the data for the object in a new tab and it appears perfectly. Why is this happening and what can I do to have a clean, consistent appearance across browsers?

Comment: scrolling doesn't seem to be a valid attribute for object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object maybe one of the reasons , try style via display + overflow.  apprently only avalaible for iframe and frame : https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-scrolling-attribute.php  ... IE11 would be a good guy here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE11:

> Support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS, not HTML files.

[Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

Comment: I ended up getting them to replace it with an actual `<iframe>` tag and it worked as expected. Thanks!